# Saving into multiple entities - Core Data - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Hopefully this will make sense.

I am trying to store data into 2 different entities from one function but not having much luck with storing data into the second entity.

My 2 entities are called - **Job** & **ShootKitChecklist**.

I have created a core data manager, I have stripped this back to just show you the section I am using:

```
struct CoreDataManager {

static let shared = CoreDataManager()

let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    // initialization of core data stack
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TBAShootCoreData")
    container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("loading of store failed: \(error)")
        }
    }
    return container
}()

func createSKCItem(item: String, used: Bool, visible: Bool, job: Job) -> (ShootKitChecklist?, Error?) {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    // create Shoot kit item
    let SKC = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ShootKitChecklist", into: context) as! ShootKitChecklist

    SKC.job = job

    SKC.setValue(item, forKey: "item")
    SKC.setValue(used, forKey: "used")
    SKC.setValue(visible, forKey: "visible")

    do {
        try context.save()
        return (SKC, nil)
    } catch let error {
        print ("Failed to add Shoot Kit Item:", error)
        return (nil, error)
    }
}
```

}

When I try to save the data, the Job entity (**First Entity**)writes to the context and I can fetch it in another class.

The data I am trying to save to the ShootKitChecklist is from an array so I put my setValues into a for look. However, it seems to ignore saving any data to the entity.

```
var SKCequipment = ["A","B","C","D","E"]

@IBAction private func HandleSave(sender : UIButton) {



        let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let job = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Job", into: context)
        let SKC = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ShootKitChecklist", into: context)

        job.setValue(jobBrandTextField.text, forKey: "jobBrand")
        job.setValue(jobNameTextField.text, forKey: "jobName")
        job.setValue(directorTextField.text, forKey: "directorName")
        job.setValue(agencyTextField.text, forKey: "agencyName")
        job.setValue(prodCoTextField.text, forKey: "prodCoName")


        for item in SKCequipment {
            print(item)
            SKC.setValue(item, forKey: "item")
            SKC.setValue(true, forKey: "used")
            SKC.setValue(true, forKey: "visible")
        }

        do {
            try context.save()
            dismiss(animated: true) {
                self.delegate?.didAddJob(job: job as! Job)
            }
        } catch let saveError {
            print("Failed to save company:", saveError)
        }
    }
```

To test to see if the items have been added to the core data I am fetching the items like this:

```
guard let SKCitem = job?.skc?.allObjects as? [ShootKitChecklist] else { return}
self.skcitems = SKCitem
print(skcitems)
```

Thank you in advance, huge help!

Comment: In `HandleSave` you create a new `Job` and a new `ShootKitChecklist`, not connected in any way. So how is this newly created `job` supposed to know about any skc?

Comment: You have a for loop that is modifying the one `SKC` object. Did you want to insert a separate SKC for each entry in thenarray?

Comment: @Paulw11 - yes I am trying to write each of items in the SKCequipment array to the **ShootKitChecklist** entity

Comment: So you need to allocate an new SKC entity instance *inside* the for loop. Also, is there any reason you aren't using the NSManagedObject subclasses that CoreData creates for you?

Comment: Also, returning a tuple is a bit icky. Your function should return an optional and simply throw an error

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for all the pointers, why are tuples icky? I haven't had any problems with them as of yet.

Comment: Your approach works, but it just isn't the conventional approach. Optional/throw is.  when you `throw` error handling moves to a `catch` clause, or your caller can even `throw` to their caller. This code may be for your own use, but if I were looking at it I would have to spend some time working out what you were doing compared to the standard approach.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. I will definitely look into the more standard approach. I am doing this as a hobby so I don't know all the standartd/proper methods yet - Good to get any tips possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have fixed it by adding another function to my protocol and appending the Entity in the delegate(I realise that I didn't share this before (apologies). Here is my new protocol:

```
protocol NewJobControllerDelegate {
    func didAddJob(job : Job)
    func didAddSKC(SKC : ShootKitChecklist)
}
```

And then in my HandleSave action I changed my for loop to this:

```
for item in SKCequipment {
            let tuple = CoreDataManager.shared.createSKCItem(item: item, used: true, visible: true, job: job as! Job)
            if let error = tuple.1 {
                print("Cannot save items", error)
            } else  {
                self.delegate?.didAddSKC(SKC: tuple.0!)
            }
```

And finally my new function from my delegate:

```
func didAddSKC(SKC: ShootKitChecklist) {
        ShootKit.append(SKC)
    }
```

Thank you for your help!